# Load balance writable files among servers

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

Let's say there are N servers S1, S2.... SN

They are keeping x1, x2, ... xn total data files on disk, and out of which writable files are y1, y2,...yn respectively.

The task is to balance out the writable files among the servers using following different approaches :

Just based on writable files count
Based on ratio of writable files / total files
For 1/ I can just do a average `(y1 + y2 + .... + yn) / n` and then load balance, but for 2/ does any algorithm exists?

Comment: You say "...but for 2/..." but I have no clue what 2/ is referring to.